# Reptile identification - Is this a green iguana?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

At first instance it looks like an iguana and since this photo was taken near the coast of [Pernambuco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pernambuco), Brazil it could only be the green iguana, but as you can see from the photo the reptile is black. Perhaps green iguanas can be black under strict circumstances, but I could not find any instances concerning that from a reputable source, only from some dubious pet blogs and it was due to the lighting, temperature and overall cage conditions. It's worth noting that there were multiple animals and they were all black. In response to *tyersome* comment, the picture was taken in summer so I'm gonna assume it was hot at the time, regarding the size it seems to have almost 2 meters. This has to definitely be from the *Iguanidae* family and it appears to share similarities with the green iguana but the color is off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You've done a good job of providing information, but it would be helpful if you could add: 1) an estimate of the iguana's size; and 2) as much environmental, habitat and behavioral information you can. In particular, was it cool/cold when the picture was taken?

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I've updated the post. Also added another photo that I've found.

Comment: Could be a hybrid or simply a melanistic green iguana.

Comment: Never heard of this melanistic phenomenon before, very interesting. That might be it, many thanks.